# use CGI qw (:standard); while I use this code in my Perl CGI script, I got a syntax error message. What is wrong?

Tags: perl, cgi.pm

Here is my Perl-CGI code to perform certain word search.   My WEB-Server is running CGI.pm module, nevertheless I got an error message further below.   How may I fix this error?    Thanks.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
# cgi59_inst_us01.pl < cgi52.pl
#
# The Search by WORD.
# 

use CGI qw (:standard);

$keyword_1 = param(keyword);
$query_keyword = $keyword_1;
### Now, the above Sub-rountine returning _keyword_1 and _keyword_2
$query_length = length($query_keyword);



use lib '.';
if( $query_length <= 1 ){
require 'cgi59_search_header.pl';
     print "<font color="#ff0000"> <br>";
     print "Please type a word or words likely in a title of the music.";
     print "</font>";
require 'cgi59_search_footer.pl';
} else {


       $counter=0;    ##  Works as GLOBAL

       require 'cgi59_search_header.pl';



       open (IN, "/var/www/db1/concatenate_distilled.txt") or die("error:$!");
       while ( my $line = <IN> ){
          ###   _keyword_1 is ASCII and with [i]. while _keyword_2 is EXTENDED and no [i].
          if (  ( $line =~ /$keyword_1/i )  ||  ( $line =~ /$keyword_2/ ) ) {   
          ($Composer_Name, $Work_ID, $Performer_Name, $Performer_fn, $Category, $Op_No, $Title, $Dummy) = split ('\t', $_);
#          print qq { <tr><td><b> $Composer_Name :      </b></td> };
#          print qq {     <td><b> $Op_No :              </b></td> };
#          print qq {     <td><b> $Title                </b></td></tr> }; 
          print "<b>·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><a 
href=\"http://110.3.33.130/cgi-bin/cgi60.pl?composer_name=$Composer_Name&work_id=$Work_ID\"> $Composer_Name, $Op_No, $Title </a><br>";  
          $counter++;
          }
       }
       close (IN);


       if($counter==0){
            print "<font color="#ff0000"> <br>";
            print "No item found, try another search or wait until coming revision of database.";
            print "</font>";
       }

       print "</table>";
       ##  Closing Output Table Formatter

       require 'cgi59_search_footer.pl';


}  ## query_length check < word must be more than 2 chars > BIG IF_ELSE -loop closing.
```

HERE IS THE ERROR MESSAGE, RUNNING SYNTAX TEST AT THE TERMINAL.

```
$bash cgi59_inst_us02.pl
cgi59_inst_us02.pl: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
cgi59_inst_us02.pl: line 7: `use CGI qw (:standard);'
```

I posted my Perl-CGI code, which returned a systax error.   Thus, I am asking around programmers here to find out what is the problem in my Perl-code.

Comment: Tip: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. You effectively did `use warnings;` (by using `-w`), but `use strict;` is just as important.

Comment: Sometime ago, I tried [ use strict; use warnings; ].    But unfortunately, my trial ends up an error.    Then I didn't pursue further, but I just stayed at old code -w.    Well, let me challenge again.    As I am getting familiar in STACKOVERFLOW about how to post the CODEs.    Let me see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking `bash` to execute a Perl script. Bash doesn't know anything about Perl.

If you set the file's permissions correctly, you can use

```bash
./cgi59_inst_us02.pl
```

That is short for

```bash
/usr/bin/perl -w ./cgi59_inst_us02.pl
```

Comment: Thanks.   Your answer is the perfect one.    I got it what was wrong.    Many, many thanks.

Comment: The way to signal that is by checking the mark next to the answer.

Comment: @MitsuruKido Be a good StackOverflow citizen and mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @stevieb   Hi!   how to mark the answer as correct?

Comment: There is a check mark, which said Accept this answer if it solved.    I  will click onto it.